# In Mule/Dataweave how do I transform a HashMap into a Array when both key & value are numbers

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

In Mule/Dataweave how do I convert/transform a HashMap into a Array. I have got a HashMap whose key & value are dynamic numbers.

Example:

```
{"3.2" : 1, "22" : 8, "2.0" : 1}
```

I want to transform it to this structure:

```
[
  {
    "name": "app-a",
    "value1": 3.2,
    "value2": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "app-a",
    "value1": 22,
    "value2": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "app-a",
    "value1": 2,
    "value2": 1
  }
]
```

Solution (Thanks to @Sulthony H)

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload pluck $$ map {
value1: ($ as :string) as :number,
value2: payload[$]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to transform a HashMap into an Array, I will do the following steps:

1. Iterate the HashMap by its *key* using **pluck** operator in DataWeave: `payload pluck $$ map {}`
2. Transform the *key* as **number**: `value1: ($ as :string) as :number`
3. Get the value based on that *key*: `value2: payload[$]`

Comment: Awesome. Perfect solution. I have also updted by question with the actual weave code.

Answer (score 1):

Another different solution:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    ($ mapObject {
        name: "app-a",
        value1: $$ as :string,
        value2: $
    })
}
```

1 - Use the map operator to iterate on the list of elements. payload map

2 - Use mapObject on each of the element of your array $ mapObject. With mapObject, $$ refers to the key name, $ refers to the value

3 - print out the values with  value1: $$ as :string, value2: $

Even more simple...

```
payload pluck (
    {
        value1:$$,
        value2:$
    }
)
```